# Adding attributes in the current_user devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

In my Rails application , I have a class that represents the users of my system . But there are some attributes that are not in this class I would like to set them on my current_user .

I created a attr_acessor with a parameter but this parameter was not included in this current_user object.

How can I change the current_user at runtime ? I mean, do not modify the attribute values ​​but add new features to it.

Comment: Consider including some example code or output to provide enough context for someone attempting to answer your question. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: It seems likely that this is indeed a duplicate of the nominated exemplar.  There's not enough information here to know for sure.  I'll mark this as a duplicate, but if that's an error on my part--if it isn't really a duplicate--please ask a new question with more detail.  Please add minimal code examples showing what you tried, explaining what you expected to happen vs. what actually happened.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the sparse information in your question, I suggest either of two ways:

**1) Use a migration** to add new attributes to your user model.

See: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html

```
$ rails generate migration AddAttrToUsers whatever:string verified:boolean verfied_at:datetime
      invoke  active_record
      create    db/migrate/20160701234500_add_attr_to_users.rb
$ cat db/migrate/20160701234500_add_attr_to_users.rb 
class AddAttrToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :whatever, :string
    add_column :users, :verified, :boolean
    add_column :users, :verfied_at, :datetime
  end
end
$ rake db:migrate
```

---

—OR—

**2) Use a combination of `attr_accessor` and `before_filter`.**

See:

- http://rubyinrails.com/2014/03/17/what-is-attr_accessor-in-rails/
- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters

_

```
# app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :some_attr
end

# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :add_attrs_to_current_user

  def add_attrs_to_current_user
    current_user.some_attr = "rad!"
  end
end

# app/views/users/show.html.erb
<%= current_user.some_attr %>
```